# Nest an IF statement inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array as follows

```
<?php
$args = array(
"post_author_url" => "no",
"thumbnail_custom_field" => "image",
"post_include" => get_user_meta($userID, 'member_owner', true),
"layout_mode" => "multi_column","layout_num_cols" => "3");
special_recent_posts($args);
?>
```

This works great, but I want to have a Condition on one of the items

`"thumbnail_custom_field" => "image",`

The `"image"` might not exist so I need a fall back so it displays OK.

for example:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true)) {
echo 'image'
} else { 
echo 'image-fallback'
?>
```

How can I have the `image` tag in the array set as a result of this IF statement? Do I make it a string before the array? or do I put the IF statement directly into the array? looking for a bit of expert guidance..thanks

Comment: weird, why did this get question get a negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$args = array(
"post_author_url" => "no",
"thumbnail_custom_field" => ((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true))?'image':'image-fallback'),
"post_include" => get_user_meta($userID, 'member_owner', true),
"layout_mode" => "multi_column","layout_num_cols" => "3");
special_recent_posts($args);
?>
```

The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE. Lookup "Ternary Operator".

Comment: on SO it is common practice that there is a explanation of what is done. `Try the following` is **NOT** a answer!

Comment: thanks man, just tested this out and worked a charm. seems some haters out today as this question got a -1 from someone...no idea why boooo ...thanks again..

Comment: I think this question is more wordpress related, so it should be on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, but hey....